# "Bad Request" when uploading JSON-file to API with R, Content-Type considered txt/html

Tags: json, r, api

I've run into a problem which I can't seem to solve while trying to use an API from within R. So I'm hoping you guys can give me a hint here what's wrong.

What I'm trying to do is make the Botometer API (https://market.mashape.com/OSoMe/botometer) accessible from within R. I know that there's a Python package for it, but since I've just learned R I thought it'd be fun to make it run with R. I've written a function to gather all the relevant information about an user with the rtweet package and parse it into a json file that should have a format accepted by the API. However, when trying to upload the json data, I get the following result from the API:

```
Response [https://osome-botometer.p.mashape.com/2/check_account]
  Date: 2017-09-17 17:19
  Status: 400
  Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
  Size: 192 B
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<title>400 Bad Request</title>
<h1>Bad Request</h1>
<p>The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this ser...
```

When using the example payload provided by the API devs, however, I get the proper result:

```
Response [https://osome-botometer.p.mashape.com/2/check_account]
  Date: 2017-09-17 15:59
  Status: 200
  Content-Type: application/json
  Size: 298 B
{
  "categories": {
    "content": 0.39, 
    "friend": 0.54, 
    "network": 0.44, 
    "sentiment": 0.33, 
    "temporal": 0.56, 
    "user": 0.24
  }, 
  "scores": {
...
```

The most likely cause of the error right now seems to be that the Content-Type is not considered JSON for my request and as thus not accepted by the server (correct me if I'm wrong).

Here's the code I'm using to make the JSON file (utilizing jsonlite and rtweet):

```
Tweetson <- function(x) {
  user.json <- lookup_users(x, token = twitter_token, parse = FALSE) %>% toJSON(null = "null", na = "null", pretty = TRUE)
  timeline.json <- get_timeline(x, token = twitter_token, parse = FALSE, n = 200) %>% toJSON(null = "null", na = "null", pretty = TRUE)
  mentions.json <- search_tweets(paste("@",x), token = twitter_token, parse = FALSE, n = 100) %>% toJSON(null = "null", na = "null", pretty = TRUE)
  payload <- paste("{\n\"timeline\":", timeline.json, ",\"mentions\":", mentions.json, ",\"user\":", user.json, "\n}")
  write(payload, "testload.json")
}
```

I then upload the file to the API, running into the aforementioned problem. (This will later be done in one function, since the issue seems to be in the making of the json file, however, I didn't include the rest here). 
Checking with external json viewers or the isValidJSON() function it seems that "testload.json" is a valid json file, so how comes the API disagrees and  denies my request? Am I oblivious to something obvious in the working of json files?

Oh, and one more thing I can't figure out (which probably has an obvious solution): how do I make R show me the API's whole answer without restricting it as seen above?

I'm fairly new to R and coding as a whole, so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Edit: This is the code I'm using to make the request to the API:

```
    POST(botometerURL,
              add_headers(
              "X-Mashape-Key"=MashapeKey,
              "Content-Type" = "application/json",
              "Accept" = "application/json"),
            body=upload_file("testload.json"),  
            encode = "json")
```

As mentioned, this works fine with the example payload but fails me with my self-generated ones.

Comment: "Content-Type is not considered JSON for my request" what method are you using to upload the file?

Comment: I'm using body=upload_file() in my POST request, which works fine for the example payload provided by the API's devs. I've tried with setting an object (that is, my testload in the environment) as the body as well with no result